# Limpiar el buffer en C

Tags: array, buffer

En este programa al realizar conversiones seguidas de arabigo a romano sin cerrar el programa el nuevo resultado se muestra agregando el valor previo de la anterior conversión a la izquierda y no sé cómo limpiar el buffer para que esto no ocurra.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>

char * de_arabigo_a_romano(int numeroArabigo);
void mostrar_resultado_de_arabigo_a_romano(char roman[]);
char *a2roman (int valor, char *c1, char *c2, char *c3);

void clrscr();

int numeroArabigo=1;
char roman[15] = "";     /* "roman" contiene la cadena "arábigo-romano */

int main()
{
    int op;
    do
    {
        /* Limpiar la pantalla */
        clrscr();
        printf("Este programa convierte de n£meros ar bigos a romanos y viceversa\n");
        printf("Ingrese la opci¢n deseada\n");
        printf("   1. De ar bigo a romano\n");
        printf("   2. De romano a ar bigo\n");
        printf("   3. Salir\n");
        printf("Elija una opci¢n (1-3): \n");
        scanf("%d",&op);
        switch (op)
        {
        case 1:
            de_arabigo_a_romano(numeroArabigo);
            mostrar_resultado_de_arabigo_a_romano(roman);
            break;
        case 2:
            //de_romano_a_arabigo(letraR);
            //mostrar_resultado_de_romano_a_arabigo (numR);
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("Gracias, vuelva pronto\n");
            break;
        default:
            printf("Opci¢n no v lida\n");
            exit (0);
        }
        printf("Presione enter para continuar\n");
        getch();
    }
    while (op!=3);
    
    return 0;
}

char * de_arabigo_a_romano(int numeroArabigo){
    //int numeroArabigo = 1;   /* Inicialización para leer al menos una vez  */
    int result;                /* "result" almacena el valor de la posición  */
            
    /* Este ciclo perminte continuar si "numeroArabigo" ar bigo se encuentra
    en el rango */
        
    do
    {
        
        /* Imprimir un mensaje al usuario */
        printf ("Ingrese un entero en el rango de 1 a 3000: \n\t");
        
        /* Leer el valor */
        scanf ("%d", &numeroArabigo);
    }
    while ((numeroArabigo < 1) || (numeroArabigo > 3000));
    
    /* Obtener el valor de los "miles" */
    if ((numeroArabigo <= 3000) && (numeroArabigo >= 1000))
    {
        result = numeroArabigo / 1000;
        strcat (roman, a2roman(result, "M", " ", " "));
        numeroArabigo -= (result * 1000);
    }
    
    /* Obtener el valor de las "centenas" */
    if ((numeroArabigo < 1000) && (numeroArabigo >= 100))
    {
        result = numeroArabigo / 100;
        strcat (roman, a2roman(result, "C", "D", "M"));
        numeroArabigo -= (result * 100);
    }
    
    /* Obtener el valor de las "centenas" */
    if ((numeroArabigo < 100) && (numeroArabigo >= 10))
    {
        result = numeroArabigo / 10;
        strcat (roman, a2roman(result, "X", "L", "C"));
        numeroArabigo -= (result * 10);
    }
    
    /* Obtener el valor de las "unidades" */
    if ((numeroArabigo < 10) && (numeroArabigo >= 1))
    {
        strcat (roman, a2roman(numeroArabigo, "I", "V", "X"));
    }
    return roman;
}
    
    char * a2roman (int valor, char *c1, char *c2, char *c3)
    {
        int i;   /* "i" es el índice de iteraciones */
        char rRoman[15] = "";
        
        char *retRoman = rRoman;
        
        /* Si "valor" = 1, 2, 3 */
        if ((valor >= 1) && (valor <= 3))
        {
            for (i = 0; i < valor; i++)
                strcat (rRoman, c1);
        }
        
        /* Si "valor" = 5, 6, 7, 8 */
        if ((valor >= 5) && (valor <= 8))
        {
            strcat (rRoman, c2);
            
            for (i = 0; i < (valor - 5); i++)
                strcat (rRoman, c1);
        }
        
        /* Si "valor" = 4 */
        if (valor == 4)
        {
            strcat (rRoman, c1);
            strcat (rRoman, c2);
        }
        
        /* Si "valor" = 9 */
        if (valor == 9)
        {
            strcat (rRoman, c1);
            strcat (rRoman, c3);
        }
        return (retRoman);
    }
    
    void mostrar_resultado_de_arabigo_a_romano(char roman[])
    {
        printf ("El n£mero romano es: \n");
        for (int i = 0 ; roman[i] != '\0' ; i++){
            printf("%c",roman[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        free(roman);
    }

    void clrscr()
    {
        HANDLE hStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
        COORD coord = {0, 0};
        DWORD count;
        CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
        GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hStdOut, &csbi);
        FillConsoleOutputCharacter(hStdOut, ' ',
                                   csbi.dwSize.X * csbi.dwSize.Y,
                                   coord, &count);
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(hStdOut, coord);
    }
```

Comment: `free` es para liberar memoria reservada con `calloc` o `malloc`. No sé qué uso pretendes darle pero eso hace que el programa crashee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para "limpiar el buffer", es decir quitar el valor previo almacenado en el arreglo `roman` se puede usar la función `memset`.

Simplemente se debe agregar la instrucción `memset(roman, '\0', sizeof(roman[0]) * 15);` antes del primer `do`

Quedaría así:

```
char * de_arabigo_a_romano(char roman[])
{
    int result;                /* "result" almacena el valor de la posición  */
    int numeroArabigo=1;     /* Inicialización para leer al menos una vez  */
    /* Este ciclo permite continuar si "numeroArabigo" ar bigo se encuentra
    en el rango */

    /* Limpia el arreglo roman para que no contenga valores anteriores. */
    memset(roman, '\0', sizeof(roman[0]) * 15);

    do
    {
        /* Imprimir un mensaje al usuario */
        printf ("Ingrese un entero en el rango de 1 a 3000: \n\t");
        /* Leer el valor */
        scanf ("%d", &numeroArabigo);
        while(getchar() != '\n');
    }
    while ((numeroArabigo < 1) || (numeroArabigo > 3000));
.
.
.
```

Con eso no es necesario liberar el arreglo `roman` con `free`, simplemente se debe remover esa instrucción. El procedimiento `mostrar_resultado_de_arabigo_a_romano(char roman[])` quedaría así:

```
void mostrar_resultado_de_arabigo_a_romano(char roman[])
{
    printf ("El valor en n£mero romano es: \n");
    for (int i = 0 ; roman[i] != '\0' ; i++)
    {
        printf("%c",roman[i]);
    }
    printf ("\n\n\t\t\t...Presione cualquier tecla para terminar.");
    getch();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Todo lo que tienes que hacer es poner un cero en el primer caracter de `roman` antes de comenzar la conversión ya que `strcat` comienza a agregar caracteres desde ahí. Para estar más seguro puedes llenar todo el buffer de ceros:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    roman[i] = 0;
```

Por cierto, tu función `a2roman` devuelve un puntero a una variable local, cuyo tiempo de vida termina al salir de la función. No deberías hacerlo.

---

Para mejorar ese aspecto y hacer el código más legible y reutilizable, te propongo trabajar de la siguiente manera: no usar variables globales. Todo lo que necesitan las funciones debe ingresar como parámetro. Por ejemplo:

```
// Convierte un entero a números romanos y lo guarda en *salida*
// numeroArabigo: el número a convertir
// salida: lugar donde se guarda el resultado
// largoSalida: tamaño de *salida*. Se tiene en cuenta para no exceder su tamaño.
// Devuelve el largo del resultado, puede ser menor a *largoSalida*.
int de_arabigo_a_romano(int numeroArabigo, char* salida, int largoSalida);

// Muestra el número romano, hasta un máximo de *largo* caracteres.
void mostrar_resultado_de_arabigo_a_romano(char* roman, int largo);

// La descripción que toque
// salida: lugar donde se guarda el resultado
// largoSalida: tamaño de *salida*. Se tiene en cuenta para no exceder su tamaño.
// ...
// Devuelve el largo del resultado, puede ser menor a *largoSalida*.
int a2roman(int valor, char* salida, int largoSalida, char* c1, char* c2, char* c3);
```

Y las utilizarías así:

```
// Variables locales
int numeroArabigo = 1;
char roman[15] = "";
de_arabigo_a_romano(numeroArabigo, roman, 15);
```

Comment: Tira advertencia: warning: 'sizeof' on array function parameter 'roman' will return size of 'char *' [-Wsizeof-array-argument]|

Comment: @Alejandro olvidé cambiarlo. En lugar de sizeof() debes escribir el número de elementos del arreglo.